# Rails: Difference between List and Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, rest, controller, indexing

I appreciate this is an incredibly noob question, but having Googled multiple combinations of search terms I regretfully am still in the dark. These things can be difficult when one doesn't know and so obvious when one does.

I have semi-home page where incoming customers can choose to see a queried list or do a handful of other things. This isn't a home page but a sort of mini 'switchboard' within the site.

The seven standard RESTful Rails controller methods are (as I understand them):

```
List # shows a list of records generated with .find(:all)
Show # shows details on one record
New # initiates new record
Create # saves and renders/redirects
Edit # finds and opens existing record for edit
Update # updates attributes
Delete # deletes record
```

1. What to use when some users need to see a selected 'list' of records that isn't literally .find(:all)? How would this work given I still need a list function that gives me .find(:all) for other purposes?
2. I've heard of 'index' being used in Rails controllers, but I don't know the difference between index and list.
3. For best practice and best design, what controller methods would you use for a mini-switchboard (and other intermediate pages such as 'About Us')?

Any specific answers would be a bit more useful than links to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html etc. :) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think it's important to note that the "standard methods" are neither standard nor methods in a sense.  These are considered actions, and are only standard in that they are the conventions used with scaffolding.  You can create any number of actions and group them logically with a controller.

If you open up **[Project]/config/routes.rb** and read through the comments, I think you'll understand a little better how controllers and actions map to a specific route.  For instance, you can create a named route to the login controller's login action and call it authenticate by adding to the top of your routes.rb:

```
# ex: http://localhost/authenticate
map.authenticate 'authenticate', :controller => 'login', :action => 'login'
# map.[route] '[pattern]', :controller => '[controller]', :action => '[action]'

#  ex: http://localhost/category/1
map.category 'category/:id', :controller => 'categories', :action => 'list'

# ex: http://localhost/product_group/electronics
map.search 'product_group/:search', :controller => 'products', :action => 'list'
```

To partially answer your question, you may want to consider adding a category model and associating all products to a category.  then, you can add a named route to view items by category as in the code block above.

The major benefit to using named routes is that you can call them in your views as `category_url` or `category_path`.  Most people don't want to do this and rely on the default route mappings (at the end of the routes.rb):

```
 # ex: http://localhost/category/view/1
 map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

 # ex: http://localhost/category/view/1.xml
 # ex: http://localhost/category/view/1.json
 map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

The key thing to mention here is that when a URI matches a route, the parameter that matches against a symbol (:id, or :search) is passed into the params hash.  For instance, the search named route above would match a search term into `params[:search]`, so if your products have a string column called 'type' that you plan to search against, your products controller might look like:

```
class Products < ApplicationController
  def list
    search_term = params[:search]
    @products = Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["type = ?", search_term])
  end
end
```

Then, the view `[Project]/app/views/products/list.html.erb` will have direct access to `@products`

If you'd really like an in-depth view into Ruby on Rails (one that is probably 10 times easier to follow than the guide in the link that you posted) you should check out
[Agile Web Development with Rails: Second Edition, 2nd Edition](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails)

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed reply Jim. I really do appreciate the time. Part of my query is simply the distinction between the term 'list' and the term 'index'. How are these two used differently?

Comment: The difference between the words is a matter of preference.  'Index' is borrowed from file-based web servers where, for example, 'index.html' is the starting point when accessing a directory.  You could easily call this controller action 'main', 'start' or anything else.  I personally only use an index action in the controller that I map as the root for the rails application.  Then, I try to make sure all controller actions are verbs after that.  My reason is that most apps will have one entry point, then everything else fires because of a user action.